# Let $X$ be a normed vector space. Let $T,S$ be bounded linear operators such that $T^2=T,S^2=S,ST=TS$. Show either $T=S$ or $\|T-S\|\geq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a normed vector space.  Let $T,S$ be bounded linear operators such that $T^2=T,S^2=S,ST=TS$. Show either $T=S$ or $\|T-S\|\geq 1$.

My observations:

$1\leq\|S\|,1\leq \|T\|$

$\|T-S\|=\|T^2-S^2\|\leq\|T-S\|\|T+S\|$ Thus $1\leq \|T+S\|$

I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\|T\|$?

Comment: Should be $||T||=\max\{||T(x)|| \mid ||x||=1\}$

Comment: Yes, i mean the operator norm.

Comment: The only missing point here is to do case analysis on whether $S = T$ when doing the cancellation on the last line of your observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider two cases:

1. $\ker T \neq \ker S$. Then WLOG we may assume that there exists $x \in \ker S \setminus \ker T$. Then $Tx \neq 0$ while $Sx = 0$. So
   $$ (T-S)(Tx) = T^2x - STx = Tx - TSx = Tx, $$
   and so, $ \| T - S \| \geq 1$.
2. $\ker T = \ker S$. We note that $\operatorname{im}(1-T) \subseteq \ker T = \ker S$. So, for any $x$,
   $$ Sx = S((1-T)x + Tx) = S\underbrace{(1-T)x}_{\in \ker S} + STx = STx. $$
   By the same argument, we have $Tx = TSx = STx$ for all $x$. Therefore $T = S$.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your matrices are projection matrices (which can always be diagonalized), and given that they commute it follows they can be simultaneously diagonalized, i.e.
$$S = Q D_S Q^{-1}, ~ T = Q D_T Q^{-1}$$
for some invertible $Q$ and diagonal matrices $D_S$ and $D_T$. Since $S$ and $T$ are both projections, the diagonal entries of $D_S$ and $D_T$ are either zero or one. It thus follows that unless $S = T$, $S - T$ has an eigenvalue of absolute value at least $1$, since
$$T - S = Q E Q^{-1} = Q (D_T - D_S) Q^{-1}$$
since the diagonal entries of $E$ (which are the eigenvalues of $S - T$) can only be $0$ (if the corresponding entries in $D_S$ and $D_T$ were the same, or either $-1$ or $1$ (if they were different).

Now we know that the operator (spectral) norm is the largest singular value, which must be greater than the magnitude of all of the eigenvalues. This is straightforward, as $\|A \vec{v} \| = |\lambda|$ for any unit eigenvector $\vec{v}$ of eigenvalue $\lambda$. Hence,
$$\|T - S\| = \max_{\|\vec{v}\| = 1} \|(T - S) \vec{v} \| \geq 1$$
unless $S = T$. $\square$